# How to install pelmet in tight spaces

Tags: wood

I would like to install pelmet over a windows which is close to end of the wall. At the corner there is also an air conditioning unit, so I only have about 12-15 cm space and the pelmet itself is already about 10 cm deep.

What is the best way to install the pelmet in that tight corner?

```
____________________
|~~; |  AC unit  |
$  ; |___________|
$  ;
$  ;
$  ;
|~~
```

**Legends**:

- $$$ = Window
- ~;~ = pelmet

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of this corner might help us understand what you're facing. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to post a picture later. Too late to take photo last night as my son was already asleep in the room.